# Can I solve a certain equation?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

Neither *Mathematica* nor Wolfram|Alpha can resolve the following. How else can I reach a solution?

```
 Reduce[(1 + x)^(2/m) - (1 - x)^(2/m) == (1 - x^2)^(1/m), x]
```

Comment: `FindInstance[(1 + x)^(2/m) - (1 - x)^(2/m) == (1 - x^2)^(1/m), {x, m}]` will give you *a* solution... restricting that to reals gives another...

Comment: @ciao Also with `FindInstance[..., Reals]` :)

Comment: @belisarius: You must have been typing as I edited my comment ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ContourPlot[
   (1 + x)^(2/m) - (1 - x)^(2/m) - (1 - x^2)^(1/m),
   {x, -.1, 1.1}, {m, .1, 5}, Contours -> {0}],
  pt = {x /. FindRoot[
      (1 + x)^(2/m) - (1 - x)^(2/m) - (1 - x^2)^(1/m),
      {x, m/5}],
    m};
  Graphics[{
    Text[ToString[Round[pt, .001]], pt, {-1.25, 0}],
    Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pt]}]],
 {{m, 1}, .1, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice use of *FindRoot*, +1

Answer (score 7):

This problem is solvable analytically, although we use Mathematica for some of the algebra.  To begin, write the initial expression as

```
(1 + x)^(2/m) - (1 - x)^(2/m) - (1 - x^2)^(1/m);
```

and divide through by the third term.

```
Expand[-%/%[[3]]] /. (1 - x^2)^(-1/m) -> (1 - x)^(-1/m) (1 + x)^(-1/m)
(* -1 - (1 - x)^(1/m) (1 + x)^(-1/m) + (1 - x)^(-1/m) (1 + x)^(1/m) *)
```

Replacing `((1 + x)/(1 - x))^(1/m)` by `z` casts the expression into the form

```
z - 1 - 1/z
```

which can be solved by

```
zsol = Solve[z - 1 - 1/z == 0, z]
(* {{z -> 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])}, {z -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])}} *)
```

Choose the second solution to obtain real `x`.

```
zsol[[2, 1]] /. z -> ((1 + x)/(1 - x))^(1/m) /. Rule -> Equal;
Solve[%, x][[1, 1]]
(* x -> (-1 + (1/2 + Sqrt[5]/2)^m)/(1 + (1/2 + Sqrt[5]/2)^m) *)
```

For comparison with the numerical solution by Bob Hanlon,

```
%[[2]] /. m -> 1 // N
(* 0.236068 *)
```

Comment: Very good. Note that `(x -> (-1 + (1/2 + Sqrt[5]/2)^m)/(1 + (1/2 + Sqrt[5]/2)^
       m)) // FullSimplify` reduces to `x -> Tanh[1/2 m ArcCsch[2]]`